# how to record in jmeter when proxy settings is configured to connect to internet

Tags: proxy, automated-tests, jmeter

To record scripts in Jmeter we need to run the proxy in local port 8080, where as in browser I need to configure for internet connectivity proxy to connect to internet.

The company I work for is providing me internet through a proxy server.

Any one who knows how to record script using Jmeter while there is already internet proxy set up in the browser to connect to internet.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the proxy server settings by running JMeter from command line like that:

```
jmeter -H [proxy server hostname or ip address] 
       -P [proxy server port]
       -u[username for proxy authentication - if required]
       -a [password for proxy authentication - if required]
```

Then you should set localhost and the port specified in **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** as the proxy address and port in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your company uses PAC file to connect to the internet. **JMeter will not execute PAC file.** Refer [JMeter is not a browser](http://jmeter.apache.org). PAC file has javascript which will not execute by JMeter.

Using browser developer tools or by asking your Network Admin or IT support team, you can get which IP being used by your company to connect to the internet.

Once you got the IP address, you can follow the steps mentioned by George in this thread to record/reply successfully.